# Creating a connection between 3 computers

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh

I have 3 machines on 3 different network.

**HOME**:

- With internet but not connected to any local machine, with sudo.

**WORK**:

- With ssh available through www internet,
- **HOME** can ssh to **WORK**, but not vice versa
- **WORK** can do both outgoing and incoming ssh
- I have **no** sudo access on this computer
- the machine has no `iptables` installed

**SERVER**:

- **SERVER** is connected to the www internet
- **SERVER** can ssh to **WORK**, but not vice versa
- **SERVER** can only do outgoing ssh.
- I have sudo access on this computer.

So now the network can do this:

> HOME -> WORK <- SERVER

Given this configuration how do i get **HOME** to connect to **SERVER**? All three machines are running Ubuntu. I only have command line access to all three machines.

Comment: My answer to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/797256/ssh-2-different-computers-behind-same-router-and-modem/797264#797264) may help you. I don't know why you can't SSH from home to server, what kind of network is server on? and does it have an internet IP or a local network IP?

Comment: then you need to forward the incoming connection to the correct local machine. Exactly what the answer I linked is about.

Comment: how do i that in command line?

Comment: I assume there's a reason you haven't installed an SSH server on the server and the home computer?  It'd be the pretty obvious easy answer, considering you have root access on both of them, unless you're behind some kind of firewall or NAT you don't have control over.

Comment: sigh, that means i've no control over the network? I can only get to my office to use the WORK to access the SERVER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need sudo for this ssh solution.

First, at the command line on the SERVER, set up a remote port forwarding from the WORK machine to the SERVER:

```
SERVER$ ssh -f -N -R 23456:SERVER:22 workuser@WORK
```

Then, as long as that process is running, you should be able to do this:

```
HOME$ ssh -t workuser@WORK ssh -p23456 serveruser@localhost
```

That is, from HOME, you should be able to connect through WORK, then through the ssh tunnel
to the SERVER machine.

It should be possible to use :23456 to specify that ssh should listen on all interfaces on
the WORK machine, but that didn't work for me, presumably because GatewayPorts was disabled.
If it worked, the second command could be simplified to this:

```
HOME$ ssh -p23456 serveruser@WORK
```

Comment: i think SERVER is behind some sort of firewall, I'm unable to ssh through the port from WORK...

Comment: Any firewall in front of SERVER shouldn't matter, as it has reached *out* through any firewall to talk to WORK, and with the -f flag, that connection should persist. Then in the second command (which you could break into two steps if you'd like), you're connecting to the pre-established tunnel, and just sending packets back over it. Can you confirm on WORK via "ps" that the connection from SERVER is still in place?

Comment: wohoo, ah, serveruser@localhost is @localhost, not the SERVER IP =) Thanks now it got through!!!

Comment: excellent! just note that if the outbound ssh tunnel from SERVER is killed for any reason (network issues, process gets killed, etc.) then you're stuck until you can get to SERVER directly again to relaunch the tunnel. You *may* want to set up a cron job to check for that tunnel and relaunch it, which may require ssh keys, etc. But you've got the basic solution now.

Comment: thanks a million, i set up a cron to spam the tunnel command every 15 mins =)